# How to get 3d view grid properties?

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to store the grid scale, but keep getting an error for being in the text editor view.

I have tried

```
bpy.context.area.type = "VIEW_3D"
print(bpy.context.space_data.grid_scale)
```

but am getting an attribute error for "SpaceTextEditor" not having a "grid_scale". However, the space does change to the 3d view, so the first line is going through.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me in 2.69, but there might be timing issues (`grid_scale` accessed but the view has not finished changing).

To get all 3D Views' `grid_scale` as a list, use:

```
grid_scales = [area.spaces[0].grid_scale for area in bpy.context.screen.areas if area.type == 'VIEW_3D']
```